# How to make everything to start from Right to left (RTL) in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme

If i want to make Arabian site how to change the direction from right to left (RTL).For example Luma logo everything should start from right to left.

Comment: you may need to create a separate theme for RTL view

Comment: how to create seperate theme.

Comment: check this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: I know to create the theme but how to make RTL in the new theme

Comment: for that you can use `html { direction:rtl; }` in css but to move blocks from left to right you have to change the structure

Comment: where i need to give html{directio:rtl;} can you please assist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68374/discussion-between-dilip-and-piyush).